# How to create virtual USB block device.?

Tags: usb, virtual-machine, usb-storage, block-device

I want to create virtual USB block device,  Example if I give "lsscsi" the USB device should present. I tried my level best, but i didnt get. So please if anybody have idea share it.

I have to connect USB device to test my project, so project always depends on USB device. So if virtually USB device present all the dependency will solve.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm not familiar with this, but if you provide what OS you are trying to do this, perhaps other users be able to help you.

Comment: What exactly did you try? What virtualization software should it run on?

Comment: OS: Linux ubuntu 4.10.0-27-generic #30~16.04.2-Ubuntu SMP Thu Jun 29 16:07:46 UTC 2017 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Comment: I'm doing report generating project, So report should be generate in USB.